# Why MVVM for Xamarin cross platform

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm asking why people are always choosing MVVM for using Xamarin on a cross-platform.

Did you think MVVM will share more code than others patterns?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*IMMO and more like an (philosophical?) opinion than an answer.*

**I Think:**

Its more about separation of concerns, scalability, than to write less code(It could be quite verbose in c# ), Perhaps the code sharing will be more like functionality sharing when it helps  to reuse modules/components/ ViewModels ...into Multiple views? ...different VM for single Models or Entities ?.

... its also the de facto mv* pattern for client side .net (as in XAML). and used by [MvvmCross](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross&ei=Ka4uUtibBebB7AbXoIGwBg&usg=AFQjCNH46EFt-2AGi9nw6QpEGItW13fkPQ&sig2=0A5HN3oQiOXIOrx_s-tqqA&bvm=bv.51773540,d.d2k) (Quite popular cross platform framework). Nothing stops you trying to use another pattern (sometimes is quite difficult to tell what pattern are you following once you are deep down in the application life cycle)

...but as I mentioned before is the "Pattern of choice for .Net UI Bindings"...the knowledge base is extensive(I think this is the key) ...so ...easy to follow and/or helpful to get back on track when things start to get untidy (as in Jenga-Code , Spaghetti, etc )

... Said that Mvc pattern is also a another choice ...check [Moncross](http://monocross.net/), also widely used in .net , but usually on the server side ...extensive knowledge base ...an applications ..that you possibly might need to extrapolate into your client side needs due to its backend origins?

Check another languages and frameworks like jscript/java/scala etc... you could use any pattern mvp/mvc/mv*whatever* but particular frameworks are prone to follow a particular pattern ( is this a pattern?).

Perhaps because language-framework's pioneers and big brains have stepped down that route and showed what can be done ...then we gladly follow their findings and advice .. .